# Where the dimensions of the object have moved in Blender 2.81

Tags: edit-mode

I'm trying to locate the dimensions of the object in 2.81. I'm watching an online tutorial made in 2.7. In Transform object properties used to be Dimension window after Scale Window. Is the window moved in another property or it became irrelevant and taken off for good? Thank you.

Comment: it's exactly the same actually

Answer (score 2):

Press N >> Item >> Transform..[image]